# How do you know when an op-amp design circuit question is inverting or non inverting or both?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

In regards to these type of questions, I am aware that this is a 3 input summing Op-Amp, however, I am unsure whether it is inverting or non inverting? How would you know from Vout whether it is the former or the latter?

Comment: Start with one and see if you can solve it with that?

Answer (score 4):

If the gain is negative then the amplifier is inverting, as it must be for \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$ in your example. If the gain is positive, such as for your \$V_1\$, then the amplifier is non-inverting.

Note that negative feedback is used for both inverting and non-inverting applications.

Comment: That is correct in case of a opamp with the rails connected to infinite and -infinite voltage and its gain and input voltages are finite.

Answer (score 3):

A general form of summing amplifier circuit might be as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW0ONX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Input resistors connected to the inverting input will tend to drive the output negative for a positive input voltage. The opposite is true of the lower set of resistors.

Your job here is to calculate plausible resistor values that yield the correct output (and decide which of the resistors shown are not necessary).

Answer (score 1):

For now, I think you will find that if the input signal is connected to the non-inverting input of the op-amp, it is a non-inverting configuration. If the input signal is connected to the inverting input of the op-amp, then it is an inverting configuration.

As another poster said, generally, the gain is positive for a non-inverting circuit and negative for an inverting circuit. Things may get more confusing later when you look at more complex circuits, but for now this should help you.